# Nontrivial pattern replacement in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to make a rule that transforms files in the format `1/2/112.jpg` into `1/2/th/112_s.jpg`.

However, `patsubst` is too weak:

```
$(patsubst /%.jpg,/th/%_s.jpg,$(var))
```

does not work, since `patsubst` wants to match the whole pattern on the string.

Is this doable somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I only use GNU make, so I never bother to learn what features are specific to it. This solution may require GNU make.)

Take it apart, alter, and reassemble.

```
$(dir $(var))$(patsubst %,th/%_s,$(basename $(var))).jpg
```

Comment: `$(var)` contains a list of filenames.

Comment: $(foreach var,$(ORIGINALS),$(dir $(var))$(patsubst %.jpg,th/%_s,$(notdir $(var))).jpg)

This is the complete solution. Thanks for your help :).